# Converting some of the rainy day fund to EUR

Tags: emergency-fund, foreign-currency, covid-19

I live in a country where EUR is accepted at most shops, but it is not the official currency. I am wondering if it would make sense to convert a portion of my rainy day fund to EUR, to be somewhat safe from the official currency going worthless.

Is it a good practice? How should I decide on the percentage, and whats better: Revolut or cash?